# Ionic Responsive Grid

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view, ionic-native

I am working on an ionic app that has a grid the grid should be verticle when in a mobile phone it should be horizontal in a tab

[image]

Comment: what is your question? and please add the relevant code

Comment: I need a responsive grid it needs to be responsive according to the screen sizes

Comment: can you post code for above output?

Answer (score 1):

You can design the grid as below:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
        1 of 4
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
        2 of 4
        </ion-col>    
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Read more [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#all-breakpoints)

Comment: i know how to design a grid i need to know how to make it responsive according to screen sizes